# Android camera setDisplayOrientation: strange behavior for galaxy tab

Tags: android, android-camera, android-2.2-froyo, galaxy-tab

I face a problem a problem trying to have a camera preview in portrait mode. I have read various articles about it and I had solved it having the following code:

```
Display display = ((CaptureActivity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8) {
    setDisplayOrientation(camera, 90);
}else{
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

where setDisplayOrientation() is defined as:

```
protected void setDisplayOrientation(Camera camera, int angle) {
    Method downPolymorphic;
    try {
        downPolymorphic = camera.getClass().getMethod(
                "setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
        if (downPolymorphic != null)
            downPolymorphic.invoke(camera, new Object[] { angle });
    } catch (Exception e1) {
    }
}
```

Now I tried this code to a Galaxy Tab and it failed. I solved it (trying and error approach) using the following code:

```
if (height == 1024 && width == 600) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
    parameters.setRotation(90);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

Now my two questions are:

1) Why there is such problem while Galaxy tab has the 2.2 version, and

2) Is there any better solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Have you checked out this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/5110406#5110406

Comment: Yeap, no luck... Thanks a lot however!

Comment: @DimitrisMakris did you get any solution for this. Please! share, I am facing same?

Answer (score 0):

for setting the display orientation check out the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29), dont just hardcode 90 degrees there.