# Android custom camera result image orientation

Tags: android, camera

I'm writing a custom camera application which follow this tutorial:
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

Now I'm able to use the camera and get the image data after user click a button.
But I got the problem that the preview is sideway so I add the following code in surfaceCreated

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //  Open the camera when the preview is created
    Log.d("Callback", "[surfaceCreated]");
    theCamera = Camera.open();

    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int displayRotation = display.getRotation();
    switch (displayRotation)  {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:        theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);    break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:       break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:      break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:      theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);   break;
    }
}
```

The preview was fine.
However when I got the image data, I use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` to get the bitmap, and set it to my imageView that is defined in my xml layout.

Here is my main.xml

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/previewSurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250px" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250px" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

previewSurfaceView is the small view that for the camera preview

button1 and button2 are the button when I clicked on, the camera capture the image and set the imagedata corresponding to imageView1/imageView2

**There are some problems:**

1. I set the layout width and height and also the max width and height to 100dp, also the scale type to fitCenter. But it seems not to display as what I want. I want the image is show inside the bound. Am I doing wrong in the layout setting?
2. The image is always in landscape even I took the picture in portrait mode.

**Besides, I want to add a button to toggle the on/off of camera but I can't figure out how to do this.**

Can somebody suggest the solution for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/5110406#5110406) as it appears to be the same issue you are having.

Comment: Sorry, I posted wrong code above. I have no problem in the surface view. But how can I get the orientation of the image data. It seems that I cant get the EXIF from the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method `setRotation` on the camera parameter object and then set the parameter on the camera.

Implement the `OrientationListener` to get the rotation use that value in `setRotation`

Sample code usage [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29).

Comment: I tried it with hardcode to 0, 90, 180 and 270. But the image data is still always in landscape. I want the image is always taken in portrait mode and display it as portrait mode too

Comment: Hold the device in potrait mode and set the rotation as 90 and you should get a picture in portrait mode.