# Images are inverted before/after saving

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm developing a new android app, and I use a surface to take a picture, and save her. When take a picture and she is saved, when I'm going to folder and open her, the image are inverted.

For exemple: If I take the picture and I'm in a left side of the screen, when I open her, I'm in the right side.

How I solved this?

```
Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length); 


try {
   bitmapPicture.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/images/image3.jpg"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That is the code I use to save the pic.

Comment: THis is a common issue on Android: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530165/android-camera-orientation-issue

Comment: The problem continues, I use the code on the link bellow: http://pastebin.com/DRcj68vX And that is the result.

Comment: I've noticed this issue can be handled differently on Android devices. I will work on some and not on others.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution so far would be to force the orientation of your surface holder:

Take a look at this page: http://hashapps.tumblr.com/post/1337347197/android-problem-of-orientation-of-camera-preview

Comment: This question sounds like mirror-image(left/right). Your answer is about the landscape/portrait issue.