# setRotation(90) to take picture in portrait mode does not work on samsung devices

Tags: android, android-camera

According to the documentation, [setRotation(90)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) should rotate the captured JPEG picture ([takePicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29) in landscape mode.

This works fine on a HTC phone, but does not work on Samsung Google Nexus S and Samsung Galaxy S3. Is this a bug?

I know that I can use the matrix transform rotation, but wish the OS can do this more efficiently, and don't want to risk over-rotating on some other devices.

**edit**

Setting `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` made the preview to be in portrait mode, however it did not have any affect on the picture taken.

Further, Besides `setRotation`, I have also tried to set the picture size - where I flip `h` with `w`: `parameters.setPictureSize(1200, 1600);`. This also did not have any affect.

**solution**

Apparently Samsung phones set the EXIF orientation tag, rather than rotating individual pixels. As `ariefbayu` suggested, reading the Bitmap using `BitmapFactory` does not support this tag. His code sample is the solution, and this solution is also compatible with using `inSampleSize`.

Comment: Check out this answer as it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/5110406

Comment: @thinksteep: no - i don't see any error via the android console.

Comment: @JohnJSmith: the answer concerns preview on a surface. My question is regarding taking a picture

Comment: I think this may also have affected the actual pictures taken as well, but it was a while ago and it was on an HTC.

Comment: @JohnJSmith: Setting camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); made the preview to be in portrait mode, however it did not have any affect on the picture taken.

Comment: I think you are talking about the effect of Exif orientation tag.

Comment: @ariefbayu: Yes - I think it is related. I read about it on the documentation for setRotation. From what I understood there is that jpeg has a way to "mark" the image as rotated, rather than rotating the individual pixels. And that some hardware might decide to rotate the pixels, while other hardware might decide to just set this Exif orientation tag. Do you think Samsung DOES set this exif tag, but the Android Bitmap does not support this tag? I use the following code to read the image back (to check that the orientation was correct):

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);

Comment: as far as I understand, from playing with Bitmap and camera. Bitmap class doesn't support Exif tag. But, I might be wrong. Need to read the documentation first (which, I don't have the time, right now).

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/26141254/1118886

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I try to answer this in relation to the Exif tag. This is what I did:

```
Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(imagePath));

Log.d("EXIF value", exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("6")){

    realImage=ImageUtil.rotate(realImage, 90);
}else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("8")){
    realImage=ImageUtil.rotate(realImage, 270);
}else if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION).equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
    realImage=ImageUtil.rotate(realImage, 180);
}
```

The `ImageUtil.rotate()`:

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int degree) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.postRotate(degree);

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
}
```

Comment: Just done some more tests. Turns out that Samsung hardware does not rotate the pixels, and only sets the exif orientation tag to number 6. I will use your utility when reading the bitmap. The good thing about this solution is that I can still keep using the inSampleSize attribute to load only a thumbnail version, and to prevent OutOfMemoryExceptions

Comment: hi, I'm having the same problem, I'm trying to implement the answer but I don't understand where this code goes. What is the variable stream? There is nothing similar in my code!

Comment: Hi, it's working fine for me, is there any other way rather than creating new bitmap (Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);), it might fire OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: But where is ImageUtil class? Where can find I it?

Comment: I dont understand where this code goes. Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Liso22, the variable stream doesn't make a difference, just plug in your bitmap, however you got it (decodeFile etc). And if you're having problems with the 'ImageUtil.rotate(), just write the 'public static Bitmap rotate()' as a method with the same parameters and make 'real image' equal that. Anyways, this solution doesn't seem to be working for me, the exif tag returns 1 (normal) whether in portrait or landscape.