# Camera on SurfaceView: set orientation of picture taken

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

this is mt code for take picture in surfaceView:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


    } catch (IOException exception) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size result = getBestPreviewSize(params, width, height);
    params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);

    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.startPreview();

}
```

the preview of picture is in portrait mode, but picture is saved on my storage rotated. How can i save picture with the same orientation of preview ?

Comment: Hi . Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but i solve it while putting a single line of code in
**surfaceChanged method**.

**params.setRotation(90);**

change your code to this:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size result = getBestPreviewSize(params, width, height);
    params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);

    params.setRotation(90)  ***//Just add this single line of code***

    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.startPreview();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity declare rotation as a static int variable

rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

Then add this lines in camera preview class

```
 if(YourActivityname.rotation == 0 || YourActivityname.rotation == 180)
        this.mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
   else
        this.mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
```

Refer this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29

> public void setRotation (int rotation)

Comment: rotation on my device is locked, and also with your code, picture is always saved rotate. But with setDisplayOrientation, i just set orientation of camera preview on surfaceView

Answer (score 0):

It is explicitly written in docs for [setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) that the system may choose to only set an EXIF flag that the image was rotated. Actually, on many devices, [e.g. Samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023696/setrotation90-to-take-picture-in-portrait-mode-does-not-work-on-samsung-device) this is exactly what happens.

You can use the [Android port](http://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil) of a [Java open source library](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/) which provides a class for lossless Jpeg rotation.