# android - Custom camera handle images in landscape

Tags: android, android-camera

I implemented the custom camera and I restricted that screen should be in portrait mode. It's working perfectly while capturing pictures in portrait mode. But While capturing the pictures in landscape, the picture was saved in the reverse orientation. Here I think, the problem is portrait mode restriction. So the capture image is saved in reversed orientation. But I want it works as similar to the default camera. How should we handle this?

Comment: This post may be useful, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023696/setrotation90-to-take-picture-in-portrait-mode-does-not-work-on-samsung-device?