# Custom Camera display orientation in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

How to maintain camera display orientation in android when i create custom camera class.
when i not perfect solution for more then android device then what i do for this scenarios and when some device do on camera landscape or some device do on camera portrait.

```
 public CameraSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);

        try {
            holder = this.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // Open the Camera in preview mode
            this.camera = Camera.open();
            this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when replaced with a new screen
        // Always make sure to release the Camera instance
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
//      Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
//      System.out.println("height...."+width+" height....."+height);
//      parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
//      camera.setParameters(parameters);
//      camera.startPreview();
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
        Camera.Size previewSize;
        if(previewSizes.size() > 1){
            previewSize =previewSizes.get(1);  // .... select one of previewSizes here
        }else{
            previewSize =previewSizes.get(0);
        }
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following two links will help you:

[Using Camera API](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html).
[Android Camera Preview is sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/5110406#5110406).

Comment: @NajibPuthawala: Welcome, if the answer help you, mark it as a answer. So it will help others when they having same query as you.

Answer (score 0):

Check orientation using orientation sensor and find angle according to angle and rotate resulted image using that angle.

```
public abstract class SimpleOrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {

    public static final int CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    private volatile int defaultScreenOrientation = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    public int prevOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
    private Context ctx;
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public SimpleOrientationListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;
    }

    public SimpleOrientationListener(Context context, int rate) {
        super(context, rate);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(final int orientation) {


        int currentOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
        int angle=0;
        if (orientation >= 330 || orientation < 30) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_0;
            angle=90;
        } else if (orientation >= 60 && orientation < 120) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_90;
            angle=180;
        } else if (orientation >= 150 && orientation < 210) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_180;
            angle=270;
        } else if (orientation >= 240 && orientation < 300) {
            currentOrientation = Surface.ROTATION_270;
            angle=360;
        }
        getset g = new getset();
        g.setK(angle);
        if (prevOrientation != currentOrientation && orientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
            prevOrientation = currentOrientation;
            if (currentOrientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN)
                reportOrientationChanged(currentOrientation);
        }

    }

    private void reportOrientationChanged(final int currentOrientation) {

        int defaultOrientation = getDeviceDefaultOrientation();
        int orthogonalOrientation = defaultOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                : Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

        int toReportOrientation;

        if (currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || currentOrientation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            toReportOrientation = defaultOrientation;
        else
            toReportOrientation = orthogonalOrientation;

        onSimpleOrientationChanged(toReportOrientation);
    }

    /**
     * Must determine what is default device orientation (some tablets can have default landscape). Must be initialized when device orientation is defined.
     *
     * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    private int getDeviceDefaultOrientation() {
        if (defaultScreenOrientation == CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) {
            lock.lock();
            defaultScreenOrientation = initDeviceDefaultOrientation(ctx);
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return defaultScreenOrientation;
    }

    /**
     * Provides device default orientation
     *
     * @return value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    private int initDeviceDefaultOrientation(Context context) {

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        boolean isLand = config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        boolean isDefaultAxis = rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180;

        int result = CONFIGURATION_ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
        if ((isDefaultAxis && isLand) || (!isDefaultAxis && !isLand)) {
            result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            result = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Fires when orientation changes from landscape to portrait and vice versa.
     *
     * @param orientation value of {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE} or {@link Configuration#ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT}
     */
    public abstract void onSimpleOrientationChanged(int orientation);

}
```

For set camera orientation for preview.

```
public static int setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        //int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        return result;

    }
```