# How to fix CameraX rotation support

Tags: android, matrix, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I faced with the issue of CameraX screen rotation support.

**Portrait**:
[image: see picture]

**Landscape:**
[image: see picure]

**Transformation code:**

```
private void updateTransform() {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateTransform: ");
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    float centerX = cameraViewTextureV.getWidth() / 2f;
    float centerY = cameraViewTextureV.getHeight() / 2f;

    switch (cameraViewTextureV.getDisplay().getRotation()) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            rotation = 0;
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            rotation = 90;
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            rotation = 180;
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            rotation = 270;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    matrix.postRotate((float) -rotation, centerX, centerY);

    cameraViewTextureV.setTransform(matrix);
}
```

So, as you can see in the pictures, camera support screen rotation not correctly... I calling `updateTransform` method when screen rotating...
Took this code from the official guide for cameraX from Android developers site.

Will be very grateful for any proposes for fixing. Have a nice day!

Comment: i see a bug in your code

Comment: @Roger, but not me...

Comment: @Roger Could you answer to my question? Where is a problem?...

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431231/6092898

Comment: Could you please try this and update me?

Comment: @Roger, thanks for your help. I don't use Camera from hardware package like the answer that you propose to me. I use CameraX from Android Jetpack, so I can't manipulate camera like there, unfortunately...

Answer (score 4):

Solution based on [AutoFitPreviewBuilder](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/utils/AutoFitPreviewBuilder.kt#L132):

```
preview.onPreviewOutputUpdateListener = Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { output ->
    // Get all dimensions
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { camera_texture_view.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val previewWidth = metrics.widthPixels
    val previewHeight = metrics.heightPixels
    val width = output.textureSize.width
    val height = output.textureSize.height
    val centerX = camera_texture_view.width.toFloat() / 2
    val centerY = camera_texture_view.height.toFloat() / 2

    // Get rotation
    val rotation = when (camera_texture_view.display.rotation) {
        Surface.ROTATION_0 -> 0
        Surface.ROTATION_90 -> 90
        Surface.ROTATION_180 -> 180
        Surface.ROTATION_270 -> 270
        else -> throw IllegalStateException()
    }
    val matrix = Matrix()
    // Rotate matrix
    matrix.postRotate(-rotation.toFloat(), centerX, centerY)
    // Scale matrix
    matrix.postScale(
        previewWidth.toFloat() / height,
        previewHeight.toFloat() / width,
        centerX,
        centerY
    )
    // Assign transformation to view
    camera_texture_view.setTransform(matrix)
    camera_texture_view.surfaceTexture = output.surfaceTexture
}
```

Comment: It works for single side but if i am rotating device to otherside it is showing reverse image, Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: this parameter we will not get in  viewCamera.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
//                updateTransform();
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

Add this code

fun onCreate

`viewFinder.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            updateTransform(1920,1080)
        }`

fun startCamera

```
preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {

        val parent = viewFinder.parent as ViewGroup
        parent.removeView(viewFinder)
        parent.addView(viewFinder, 0)

        viewFinder.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
        updateTransform(1920,1080)
    }
```

fun updateTransform(width:Int,height:Int)

```
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val previewWidth = metrics.widthPixels
    val previewHeight = metrics.heightPixels

    matrix.postScale(previewWidth.toFloat() / height,previewHeight.toFloat() /width,centerX,centerY)
```

The resolution of my device is 1920x1080

The complete code is in my repository [CameraX](https://github.com/Ange1D/CameraX)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with CameraX Alpha 06. I then solved it with Marcin Mrugas answer.
But when migrating to Alpha09, I got rid of this code and the rotation was OK.
So it seems CameraX now handles the rotation by itself.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation

> ```
> override fun onCreate() {
>     val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
>
>     val orientationEventListener = object : OrientationEventListener(this as Context) {
>         override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation : Int) {
>             // Monitors orientation values to determine the target rotation value
>             val rotation : Int = when (orientation) {
>                 in 45..134 -> Surface.ROTATION_270
>                 in 135..224 -> Surface.ROTATION_180
>                 in 225..314 -> Surface.ROTATION_90
>                 else -> Surface.ROTATION_0
>             }
>
>             imageCapture.targetRotation = rotation
>         }
>     }
>     orientationEventListener.enable()
> }
> ```

Here is the link
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try this transformation method from the official Android Camera X example project:
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/153d2d203118dacbd2afeb53b2e8be489677ed98/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/utils/AutoFitPreviewBuilder.kt#L151

I hope this helps.