# Camera X android landscape orientation for preview

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, orientation, android-camerax

I have implemented a Camera X preview which handle both portrait an landscape orientation.
Basics google params are good for portrait mode, but when I'm rotating my device the preview in landscape mode is broken the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462736/how-to-fix-camerax-rotation-support) (see pic)

```
          Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                                //.setTargetResolution(size)
                                //.setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9)
                                .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_90)
                                .build();
```

I've tried all setter I found on SO and google camera doc like `setTargetRotation` and `setTargetAspectRatio` above, and also tried with matrix but nothing change in landscape.

How can I get more or less the same full screen preview in both orientation ?

Answer (score 0):

Android camera preview transformation is a hard problem, that's why CameraX provides the [PreviewView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView) API for you. To make things simpler, you can also use the [CameraController](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/CameraController) API which creates the `Preview` class for you.

You can take a look at CameraX's test app for code samples: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/CameraControllerFragment.java

Comment: Could you provide a minimal sample code with the controller and the rotation handling for orientation preview ? I have already implemented all I found in API and doc but I'm not able make it work while the device is rotating

Comment: The minimal sample I have is probably the MLKit sample. You just need to remove the MLKit related code: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/78270451d4b79ae7ec9ee42b4b45714b122663d4/CameraX-MLKit/app/src/main/java/com/example/camerax_mlkit/MainActivity.kt