# Android camera orientation for newbie

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working with a camera and **facing problem in camera orientation**. I have found some answer over internet and I think this answer might be best fit for me.

**Can anybody give me detail instruction, [how to add this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/5110406#5110406) in my camera project.?**

Here is my [Full camera project Code.](http://www.mediafire.com/?8ht63xpteih0as3)

Direct code here

```
public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

 Camera camera;
 SurfaceView surfaceView;
 SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 boolean previewing = false;
 LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

 Button buttonTakePicture;



 final int RESULT_SAVEIMAGE = 0;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);


       getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
       surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
       surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
       surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
       surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


       controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
       View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
       LayoutParams layoutParamsControl
        = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
       this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);


       buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
       buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback,
      myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
   }});

       LinearLayout layoutBackground = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
       layoutBackground.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener(){


   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
    camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
   }});
   }

   AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(true);
  }};

   ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onShutter() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};

 PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};

 PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   /*Bitmap bitmapPicture
    = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length); */

   Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

   OutputStream imageFileOS;
   try {
    imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
    imageFileOS.write(arg0);
    imageFileOS.flush();
    imageFileOS.close();

    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this,
      "Image saved",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   camera.startPreview();
  }};

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
   int height) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(previewing){
   camera.stopPreview();
   previewing = false;
  }

  if (camera != null){
   try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);  
    camera.startPreview();
    previewing = true;
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }



 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  camera = Camera.open();
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  camera.stopPreview();
  camera.release();
  camera = null;
  previewing = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: @Vikalp Patel - Please stop suggesting edits that only insert boldface text in questions. This is distracting and doesn't improve the readability of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your camera's orientation changed your `surfaceCreated` function to rotate the camera from the default android camera default of landscape mode to portait mode (because your activity is in portrait mode):

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   camera = Camera.open();
   Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
   camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
   camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

Your app also crashes when you try and take a picture... but that is not the issue at hand... though it might have to do with you needing to add the following line to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

:)