# Capturing image via camera hardware is not working properly?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to use camera hardware to capture list of images. But while launching the Camera View the view doesn't looks like usual. The screen shot is attached below. I am testing this in `HTC Sensation running android 4.0.3`.

`Image ScreenShot while in portrait`
[image] It doesn't looks like usual camera view.

What is the problem here?

Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you plz give your code.?? i badly need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual problem with making a custom camera with Android in portrait mode. You likely have a SurfaceView that is being used to display your camera preview. I add the following line of code to my `surfaceCreated` method:

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

For more info, check out some other answers on this topic ([here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504605/camera-is-wrong-unless-keyboard-is-open/5504651#5504651), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472675/android-camera-orientation-for-newbie/14487177#14487177)). Basically, the Android camera is set to display in Landscape mode, so you need to rotate the orientation if the Activity is in portrait mode to accomodate this.

Comment: Android cameras have taken over my life :) happy to share.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Any idea about adding buttons to the view

Comment: I would like to add capture,add and zoom button in the camera view. What will be the best approach to do this?

Comment: I would probably (full disclosure I'm not too well versed in the lore of layout optimization) throw everything into a big relative layout, and as your first element you'll want an element for placing your camera preview (I usually add my surface view with the camera preview to a FrameLayout as the first element), and below that have another relative layout where you add `Button`s or `ImageButton`s with backgrounds from your drawables. No golden bullet here.. you just have to get your hands dirty with some xml.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will do some changes to my xml.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Hardware Camera is Landscape(almost many devices) , so at-once you capture , i automatically rotates to 90 degree - As if it is taken in the landscape .

Thats why you get the image right when you take in Landscape and 90degree rotated image while taking in Portrait mode .

- detect the orientation of the device and if it is in portrait , rotate to 90 degree clockwise , so that it would tally when it rotates 90degree anti-clockwise .

Use the below code to detect the orientation ,

```
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) 
        {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            {
                // code in portrait - rotate to 90 degree
            }
            else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
                    // code in landscape - do nothing
            }

        }
    }
```