# Android Surface class Surface.ROTATION_ cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-camera, surfaceholder

I'm trying to fix my camera app. When i hold the camera in landscape mode, it previews on the screen sideways.
I found this fix on stack : [Android - Camera preview is sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways)

In my `CameraSurfaceView` class constructor, I get the surface like this `this.Surface = getHolder();`.
In the `surfaceChanged` method i check the display rotation against Surface.ROTATION_<#> for 0,90,180,and 270 degrees (method below). However, each one of the `ROTATION`Surface constants is underlined with the following error `ROTATION_<#> cannot be resolved or is not a field`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My `CameraSurfaceView` is separate from my activity so I'm wondering if the display has something to do with it?
Hope this is explained correctly, if you need more code or anything let me know. I appreciate this in advance!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;


public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    int orientation = 0;

    Camera.Parameters params = Cam.getParameters();

    WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
    android.view.Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(height, width);                           
            Cam.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(height, width);                           
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(height, width);               
        }

        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
        {
            params.setPreviewSize(height, width);
            Cam.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        }


    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size previewSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height);
    params.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height); 



     int zoom = 0;
     params.setZoom(zoom);

    zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Camera.Parameters params = Cam.getParameters();
                maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
                    if(currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
                        currentZoomLevel++;
                        Cam.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    }
            }
        });

    zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Camera.Parameters params = Cam.getParameters();
                maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
                    if(currentZoomLevel > 0){
                        currentZoomLevel--;
                        Cam.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    }
            }
        });    


    Cam.setParameters(params);

    try {
        Cam.setPreviewDisplay(Surface);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Cam.startPreview();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a field named `Surface`, you cannot access the class `Surface` from within your class.

Instead, you will have to write

```
android.view.Surface.ROTATION_0
```

or rename your field.

Answer (score 0):

You've named your field `Surface`, which is also the name of the type you are trying to reference a constant from.  Rename the field so that it does not have the same name as the type, then import `android.view.Surface` and you should be able to reference `Surface.ROTATION_0` etc with no problems.

Note that Java style usually dictates you start variable names with lower case, and types with upper case, which avoids this type of conflict.