# Android - Camera provide upside down data on back camera in some devices

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, orientation

I am rendering `camera preview` on `GLSurfaceView` everything works fine but `camera preview` show upside down on some device specially on **Nexus 5X** . I have checked this solution [Android - Camera preview is sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways/5110406#5110406)
. This is my code for handling orientation problem

```
 private void setCameraDisplayOrientation() {
    Constants.debugLog(TAG_DEBUG, "setCameraDisplayOrientation");
    Constants.debugLog(TAG, "setCameraDisplayOrientation ");

    if (camera == null) {
        Constants.debugLog(TAG + " Owncamera", "setCameraDisplayOrientation - camera null");
        return;
    }

    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(currentCameraId, info);

    WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int rotation = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    int degrees = 0;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        this.cameraOrientation = 2;
    } else if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
        this.cameraOrientation = 1;
    }

    Constants.debugLog(TAG_DEBUG, "result: " + result + "  this.cameraOrientation == " + this.cameraOrientation);
    Constants.debugLog(TAG, "result: " + result + "  this.cameraOrientation == " + this.cameraOrientation);
    //Log.e("camera_orient", "res: "+ result);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

From the `Camera.CameraInfo info` class, i can get `orientation` . For maximum device the values i get on `portrait mode` is "`for front camera = 270, back camera = 90` "" but on `Nexus 5X` it provide `camera orientation` **270,270** for both front & back camera. Beside on other devices my camera provide `result` value 90 for both front and back camera in portrait mode but for `Nexus 5x` front camera 90 back camera 270. I have also tried by setting value fixed 90 on `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` Nexus 5X device but don't work
How to handle this problem so that all device camera orientation will be same and i won't get any rotated image ??

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Would be good to either select or publish an answer. Cheers.

Comment: yes. i had solved it. I am adding the answer now @JCutting8

Comment: @JCutting8 check the new answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason of problem:** By default maximum devices return an image with 90 degree default orientation while using camera api 1. I am not sure about this in case of using camera api 2. But in case of Nexus 5x and some rare device (using camera api 1) , It return image with 270 degree default rotation which is an exceptional case on some specific model device. SO you have to add an addition rotation of 180 degree for Nexus 5X. Please check printing the log of image orientation of Nexus 5X.

Comment: Will this cause issues on other devices (i.e. non Nexus 5X)?

Comment: @JCutting8 I had seen this scenario on Nexus 5x and on a Samsung Device (forget model number). You can add a fix by checking the output image orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Try

**1.** First of all, add methods (writeFile, processImage and getCorrectCameraOrientation) defined below

**2.** Calculate camera orientation after capturing photo and update onPictureTaken**

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken (final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {

    int rotationAngle = getCorrectCameraOrientation (this, info);
```

**3.** Create file and update photo angle using rotationAngle

```
File file = new File (folder, fileName);

try {
    file.createNewFile ();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
}

writeFile (data, file);
processImage (file, rotationAngle, compressRatio);
```

**writeFile**

```
public static void writeFile (byte[] data, File file) throws IOException {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream (fos);
        bos.write (data);
    }
    finally {
        if (bos != null) {
            try {
                bos.flush ();
                bos.close ();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**processImage**

```
public static void processImage (File file, int rotationAngle, int compressionRatio) {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (file.getPath ());

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
        matrix.postRotate (rotationAngle);

        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap (bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth (), bmp.getHeight (), matrix, true);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (file);
        bmp.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, compressionRatio, fos);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError t) {
        t.printStackTrace ();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace ();
    }
    finally {
        if (bos != null) {
            try {
                bos.flush ();
                bos.close ();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**getCorrectCameraOrientation**

```
    public static int getCorrectCameraOrientation (Activity activity, Camera.CameraInfo info) {

    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager ().getDefaultDisplay ().getRotation ();
    int degrees = 0;

    if (hasValidRotation (rotation)) {
        degrees = rotation * 90;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;
    }
    else {
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually i wanted image data on a particular angle from Camera. Actually i am receiving data from onPreviewFrame , from there i send that data to server for opponent and also render on my screen. I don't want any post processing. I want data in a same pattern. I don't know if it is possible or not. If possible it will be a great help for me

Comment: It's not possible using Camera API, this is old API and is deprecated now. You can achieve this using Camera2 API, which is available for android 5+. Camera2 API is stable and easy to use.

Comment: :( I had to give support from 16.  I will try camera2 for higher version but somehow I had to fix that issue.  thanks for your reply. Can you give any suggestion so that I can reotate the byte before sending to server??

Comment: oh.  I forgot to say thanks. Thank you for your reply

Comment: First of all, apply the rotation as mentioned in the answer, which will give you same image which was captured, then upload same file to server.