# Recorded video not playing in correct orientation Android media recorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am recording a video using android MediaRecorder

```
mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(degrees);
```

I used this to rotate the video. It records in correct orientation and MXplayer plays this in correct orientation. The problem is the vlc player and other players are not playing it in the correct orientation.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use EXIF flag to determine it.

Comment: How do i use EXIF while recording video. So that other players can play video in correct orientation.

Comment: other players use the exif data of your video to determine orientation so change it to portrait if you know you shot in portrait and landscape if you shot in that

Comment: also  beaware of the camera bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways

Comment: true but if i try to play it in VLC or WindowsMedia play or any other media player it will rotate video. so how do i record video so that it will be played same in all players

Comment: currently how are you determining if the video is portrait/landscape