# SurfaceView orientation

Tags: android, screen, orientation, surfaceview

I have a problem with the orientation of the photo preview. I use 
`SurfaceView`. When I try to rotate the screen 180 degrees (fast change screeen orientation), the activity is recreated good, but orientation `SurfaceView` does not change, and the preview image is upside down. But at the same time if I turn the screen slowly (at the usual speed) turn 90 degrees and without stopping at +90 degrees - everything is displayed nominally. In both variant, the photos are normal (I write orientation screen in EXIF). This problem only appears if you rotate the screen **only 180 degrees** - and **very quickly**.
Can not understand how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not SurfaceView is not changed i guess. You can check it with `surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)`, the problem is camera orientation does not change. You can check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways?rq=1).